# SonarQube not able to run with Ubuntu when using non embedded database. (elastic search failed to start)

Tags: java, ubuntu, elasticsearch, sonarqube

I tried to setup SonarQube 8 and 8.1 in my Ubuntu machine running Ubuntu 18.04 (JDK 11).
I am facing one specific issue most probably related with ElasticSearch. Whenever I am trying to start the SonarQube with sonar.sh start command it fails with following error in both es.log and sonar.log

```
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]
```

Before posting here I tried multiple things but none of them helped me to solve this issue. The things I have tried are below.

1. Tried setting values in /etc/security/limits.conf

   ```
   user  -  nofile  65535
   ```
2. Tried setting values in /etc/sysctl.conf

   ```
   vm.max_map_count=262144
   fs.file-max=65536
   ```

Even after changing these system files I am not able to start SonarQube, I always get same error mentioned above every time.

Please Note:

This only happens when I am trying to use the SonarQube along with external database, it work completely ok with embedded H2 database but whenever I enable any external DB (tried both MSSQL and Postgres) I face the same issue.

Comment: is there is any doc which you following, so that we can repro issue and help

Comment: I used this doc for installation https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around a lot finally I found that in Ubuntu you need to add below line in both `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and `/etc/systemd/user.conf` to change default open file limit.

Line to be added

```
DefaultLimitNOFILE=65536
```